# How to change string values in column, saving part of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, rename

I have a dataframe:

```
  id                 value
4_french:k_15          10
87_nov:k_82            82
11_nov:k_10            10
1_italian:k_11         9
```

I want to rename values in column id which have `nov:k_` giving them new id `k_10` or `k_82` so desired result must be:

```
  id                 value
4_french:k_15          10
k_82                   82
k_10                   10
1_italian:k_11         9
```

How to do that? I know about `str.replace()` but how to keep number at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you can use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) as follows:

```
df["id"] = df["id"].str.replace("^.+_nov:", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
               id  value
0   4_french:k_15     10
1            k_82     82
2            k_10     10
3  1_italian:k_11      9
```

The pattern `"^.+_nov:"` will remove anything from the start of the string to `"_nov:"` (included).